# How to use custom colors for background in phppresentation slide

Tags: background-color, phppresentation

I want to be able to use custom colors but can't seem to get around the styleColor constants. How can I enter my own colors like #008080

```
// Create slide
echo date('H:i:s') . ' Create slide'.EOL;
$oSlide1 = $objPHPPresentation->getActiveSlide();
$oSlide1->addShape(clone $oShapeDrawing);
$oSlide1->addShape(clone $oShapeRichText);
// Slide > Background > Color
$oBkgColor = new Color();
$oBkgColor->setColor(new StyleColor(StyleColor::COLOR_DARKGREEN));
$oSlide1->setBackground($oBkgColor);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this :

```
// Create slide
echo date('H:i:s') . ' Create slide'.EOL;
$oSlide1 = $objPHPPresentation->getActiveSlide();
$oSlide1->addShape(clone $oShapeDrawing);
$oSlide1->addShape(clone $oShapeRichText);
// Slide > Background > Color
$oColor = new StyleColor();
$oColor->setRGB('008080');
$oBkgColor = new Color();
$oBkgColor->setColor($oColor);
$oSlide1->setBackground($oBkgColor);
```